# received channel layer as None in django

Tags: python, django, redis, channel

I am using channels into python and django project. the project is in docker image and the containers are redis, celery, postgres etc. and the work is to connect to the server and receive messages from the server using the redis for that.
But the problem i am facing is i can't connect to the server and receiving the value of channel_layer as none
let me provide you the code so that finding issue will be clean and clear
so the code i updated in my settings.py file is

**settings.py**

```
`ASGI_APPLICATION = "ucm.asgi.application"

CHANNEL_LAYERS = {
    "default": {
        "BACKEND": "channels_redis.core.RedisChannelLayer",
        "CONFIG": {
            "hosts": [("redis", 6379)],
        },
    },
```

---

}`

**asgi.py**

`
import os

```
   from channels.auth import AuthMiddlewareStack
   from channels.routing import ProtocolTypeRouter, URLRouter
   from channels.security.websocket import AllowedHostsOriginValidator
   from django.core.asgi import get_asgi_application

    from hook.routing import websocket_urlpatterns
   import hook.routing

   django_asgi_app = get_asgi_application()

   application = ProtocolTypeRouter(
   {
   "http": django_asgi_app,
    "websocket": AllowedHostsOriginValidator(
    AuthMiddlewareStack(URLRouter(websocket_urlpatterns))
    ),
    }
  )
```

`**hook\\routing.py**``from channels.routing import ProtocolTypeRouter, URLRouter
from django.urls import re_path
from .ChatConsumer import ChatConsumer

websocket_urlpatterns = [
re_path(r'ws/chat/(?P<name>[^/]+)--(?P<wa_number>\d+)++(?P<mobile>\d+)/$', ChatConsumer.as_asgi()),
]

application = ProtocolTypeRouter({
'websocket': URLRouter(websocket_urlpatterns),
})``

**chatconsumers.py**
`   import json
from channels.generic.websocket import AsyncWebsocketConsumer

```
class ChatConsumer(AsyncWebsocketConsumer):
  async def connect(self):
```

#Extract data from payload
_payload = await self.receive_json()
room_data = f"{_payload['name']}--{_payload['wa_number']}--{_payload['mobile']}"

```
    # Form the room group name
    self.room_group_name = f"{room_data}"

    # Join room group
    await self.channel_layer.group_add(
        self.room_group_name,
        self.channel_name
    )
    print(self.room_group_name)

          await self.accept()
          self.send(text_data=json.dump({'status':'connected'}))


    async def disconnect(self, close_code):
    # Leave room group
         await self.channel_layer.group_discard(
             self.room_group_name,
             self.channel_name
        )

      async def receive(self, text_data):
        text_data_json = json.loads(text_data)
        message = text_data_json['message']

        # Check if user exists (this is a mockup; you might want to replace this with actual logic)
        user_exists = False

        if user_exists:
        # If user exists, continue chat
              await self.channel_layer.group_send(
                self.room_group_name,
                {
                    'type': 'chat_message',
                    'message': message
                }
            )

       async def chat_message(self, event):
        message = event['message']

           # Send message to WebSocket
            await self.send(text_data=json.dumps({
               'message': message
            }))
```

**chat/views.py**
`   class CreateRoom(generics.CreateAPIView):
def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
_payload = request.data
room_data = f"{_payload['name']}--{_payload['wa_number']}--{_payload['mobile']}"
try:
channel_layer = get_channel_layer()
if channel_layer is not None:

```
            async_to_sync(channel_layer.send)(
                {
                    "type":"room.create",
                    "name":room_data,
                    "text":_payload['text'],
                }
            )
            return Response({"message":"connection establishment"})
        else:
            print("received channel layer as",channel_layer )
            return Response({"message":"error connection establishment"})
    except Exception as e:
        print("failed to create connection to channels ",str(e))
        return Response({"message":"something went wrong", "error":str(e)})
```

`

**urls.py**
`path('create_room/', views.CreateRoom.as_view(), name='CreateRoom'),`

i have done r&d in every cases but i am receiving the error as

unified-chatbot-middleware-backend-1        | received channel layer as None
unified-chatbot-middleware-backend-1        | INFO 2023-12-20 13:00:46,876 middleware 11 140153688434368 POST /hook/create_room/
unified-chatbot-middleware-backend-1        | INFO 2023-12-20 13:00:46,876 middleware 11 140153688434368 {'Content-Length': '94', 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br', 'Accept': '*/*', 'User-Agent': 'Thunder Client (https://www.thunderclient.com)', 'Host': 'localhost:8080', 'Connection': 'close'}
unified-chatbot-middleware-backend-1        | INFO 2023-12-20 13:00:46,877 middleware 11 140153688434368 b'{\r\n  "name": "s",\r\n  "wa_number": "1234567890",\r\n  "mobile": "0987654321",\r\n  "text": "zyc"\r\n}'
unified-chatbot-middleware-backend-1        | INFO 2023-12-20 13:00:46,878 middleware 11 140153688434368 POST /hook/create_room/ - 200
unified-chatbot-middleware-backend-1        | INFO 2023-12-20 13:00:46,878 middleware 11 140153688434368 {'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Allow': 'POST, OPTIONS'}
unified-chatbot-middleware-backend-1        | INFO 2023-12-20 13:00:46,878 middleware 11 140153688434368 b'{"message":"error connection establishment"}'
unified-chatbot-middleware-backend-1        | INFO 2023-12-20 13:00:46,881 basehttp 11 140153688434368 "POST /hook/create_room/ HTTP/1.1" 200 44

i was expecting the output to send the channel_layer object but receiving None

i tried to check:

1. the container process is running or not they are running properly for all the things but not for this
2. check settings.py and asgi.py file what can be the issue but not resolved.

as i am also a starter with this python and django so if this is having the basic problem please help me